# How do i use a query to display products from a query onto a product layout page

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables, product

The function `product()` is used on a page called `products.php`. How can I make each product returned from that search (nike trainers) a clickable link to a page called `product.php` and display only that products info onto the `div`s on `product.php`?

```
/*
 * This function is used for products.php page,(search page)
 */
function product ()
{
    $get = mysql_query ("SELECT id, name, price, size, imgcover FROM products WHERE brand='nike'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == FALSE)
        { echo " There are no products to be displayed!";}
    else
        { while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){echo "<div id='productbox'><a href='product.php'>".$get_row['name'].'<br /> £'.$get_row['price']. '  UK'.$get_row['size']. '<br />' .$get_row['imgcover']. "</a></div>" ;} 
    }
}

/* The function productlayout () I am using for the product.php page and I am echoing this onto this page.  */

function productlayout ()
{
    $get = mysql_query ("SELECT id, name, price, size, buyfor, exfor, grade, brand, Basecolour,     imgcover FROM products WHERE id ='1'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($get) == FALSE)
        { echo " There are no products to be displayed!";}
    else
        { while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
            { echo "<div id='layouttitle'>".$get_row['name']."</div>
                <br /> <div id='layoutprice'>£".$get_row['price']. "</div>
                <div id='layoutsize'>UK".$get_row['size']. "</div>
                <br /><div id='layoutgrade'>Condition  " .$get_row['grade']. "</div>
                <div id='layoutbrand'>" .$get_row['brand']. "</div>
                <div id='layoutbcolour'>Base Colour - " .$get_row['Basecolour']. "</div>
                <div id='givecash'>" .$get_row['buyfor']. "</div>
                <div id='giveexchange'>" .$get_row['exfor']. "</div>";
        } 
    }
}
```

Any help would be great, been struggling with this for a while now!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your search parameter in your function and customize it like below

```
  function product ($product =NULL)
 {

 if(!empty($product)){
      $get = mysql_query ("SELECT id, name, price, size, imgcover FROM products
 WHERE brand='nike' AND `name` LIKE '%".$product."%'");
 }else{
 $get = mysql_query ("SELECT id, name, price, size, imgcover FROM products 
 WHERE brand='nike'");
 }
 if (mysql_num_rows($get) == FALSE)
 { echo " There are no products to be displayed!";}
 else
 {while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){echo "<div id='productbox'><a href='product.php'>".$get_row['name'].'<br /> £'.$get_row['price']. '  UK'.$get_row['size']. '<br />' .$get_row['imgcover']. "</a></div>" ;} 
 }
 }
```

Same `if else` blocks and a parameter to `productlayout ($product)` and use it in query

---

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).